# Sending Concatenated SMS (with more than 160 chars) in text mode

Tags: sms, at-command, sim900

I have gone through the questions about sending multipart SMS in PDU format , I am looking for a way to send them in text mode, How can I do that using AT commands

[Wikipedia - Concatenated SMS PDU Mode SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS#PDU_Mode_SMS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to send multipart SMSs in text mode. You will have to use PDU mode. Because there should be a way to concatenate the compete text at the receiver end which is achievable with header part in pdu format,but not with text mode.